# Add multiple binding via New-WebBinding

Tags: powershell, iis

I was trying to add mulitple binding on IIS via `New-WebBinding` cmdlet, but after creating 1st binding for 2nd binding it gave me Error:

```
Filename: \\?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
Error: Cannot write configuration file
```

I read article I found that IIS probably locks the file after it's adding binding. Is there any way to add multiple binding to IIS via `New-WebBinding` cmdlet.

Comment: There should be no problem using New-WebBinding several times to add multiple bindings. Something else is wrong with your setup.

Comment: I also thought that....but adding multiple binding back-to-back gave me this error and when I tried to add those binding one-by-one, it worked
What I was doing, I was adding binding to remote server via Powershell.
I got this error.

Comment: Got these error too..

`+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-ItemProperty], FileLoadEx 
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell 
   .Commands.NewItemPropertyCommand `
 
-------------

Comment: I read this [link](http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/problems/15952-error-cannot-write-configuration-file-while-setting-bindings), it tells `Researching the actual error lead me to finding that the system.applicationHost/configHistory potentially locks the configuration, which might be our root cause. I've internally changed the values to not backup the configuration as often, but that's not ideal and I'm not sure that it's actually prevented the error from happening at this point. `

So I thought someone might have some way around ..